# Remove both parentheses, brackets, etc., by removing the left one neovim

Tags: lua, neovim

Hello everyone I explain, I am reinstalling all my vim plugins (neovim) and for this reason when installing "**jiangmiao/auto-pairs**", by writing:

```
"
```

or

```
(
```

or

```
{
```

etc.
what I receive is:

```
"|"
```

or

```
(|)
```

or

```
{|}
```

**where | is the place where the cursor stays**

Now, when removing the left parenthesis, quotation mark, etc., from where the cursor is, both are not deleted, and it is what I would like.

what I do is remove the left and what I receive is:

```
|"
```

but what I want to receive is:

```
|
```

**obviously | is where the cursor stays**

I did research, and installed "**tpope/vim-surround**", but it still doesn't work, I'm using lua, for this.
**Could it be that I haven't configured "tpope/vim-surround" to use it properly?**
my installed plugins:

```
plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
plug 'alvanvim-closetag'
plug 'tpope/vim-surround'
```

my plugin configuration:

```
vim.g.closetag_filenames = "*.html,*.js,*.jsx,*.ts,*.tsx"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vim auto-pairs remove/umwrap pair of brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60954163/vim-auto-pairs-remove-umwrap-pair-of-brackets)

Comment: @Piglet What you are looking for in the question asked is not the same as mine, however they mention commands that worked for me, thank you.
This is the one that helped me and I hope it serves more people

Comment: It is not about the question but about the answers to that question. questions usually do not answer questions. answers do. the accepted answer explains how to map backspace to remove the autopair